# Firepod recording on a laptop that doesn't have a firewire port?

Tags: firewire, accessories

I bought a laptop around a year ago and unfortunately, it doesn't have a Firewire port. I'd like to use my Firepod with it, but I can't since I'm lacking the port. Is there some sort of converter I can get to make it possible for me to record?

Answer (score 2):

Check your laptop to see if it has a [PC Card (PCMCIA) slot](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5084216_pc-card-slot.html).  If so, you can get a [firewire card like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002TLT96E).  Then you will be able to use firewire directly on your laptop.

Comment: Negative on that. I don't have a PC card slot on here.

Comment: I did find one [USB to Firewire adapter](http://www.sourcingmap.com/firewire-ieee-1394-pin-male-male-usb-plug-adapter-p-62130.html), but I don't know if it would work with the Firepod.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if your laptop has a MINI firewire port, which was popular in mid-high range laptops a few years back.  Else, I'm afraid you'll need to pick up a USB audio card.

Comment: A USB audio card? What does this mean, is it a converter or a different recording interface?

Comment: You can get either a USB sound card (usually a short cable or small box with mic/line in and speaker out), or a USB recording interface (much like the Firepod).  Those designated as a recording interface are usually of much higher quality and have models available with more than 2 input channels.